# Value of $b_{5}\;,b_{6}\;\;b_{7}.$ If $b_{n}$ Rep. no. of $n$ digit integer ending with $1$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $a_{n}$ denote the number of all $n-$ digit positive integers formed by the digits $0,1$
>
> or both such that no consecutive digits in them are $0$ and $b_{n}$ denote number of such
>
> $n$ digit integers ending with digit $1$ and $c_{n}$ denote number of such
>   $n$ digit integers
>
> ending with digit $0$.
>
> $(i)\;\;\;$ Then calculate the values $b_{5}\;,b_{6}\; ,b_{7}$
>
> $(ii)\;\; $Also, find which of the following is right?

$\bf{Options::}$

> $(a)\;\; a_{17}=a_{16}+a_{15}\;\;\;\;\;(b)\;\; c_{17}\neq c_{16}+c_{15}\;\;\;\;\;(c)\;\;b_{17}\neq b_{16}+c_{16}\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\ a_{17}=c_{17}+b_{16}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here  Given $a_{n}$ Represent all $n$ Digit positive integer ending with $0,1$

and $b_{n}$ Represent such all $n$ Digit positive Integer ending with $1$

and $c_{n}$ Represent such all $n$ Digit positive Integer ending with $0$

So we get  $a_{n} = b_{n}+c_{n}.$

and $a_{1} = 1(1)\;\;,a_{2}=2(10,11)\;\;,a_{3}=3(110,101,111)\;\;,a_{4}=5(1111,1110,1101,1011,1010)$

and $b_{1}=1(1)\;\;,b_{2}=1(11)\;\;,b_{3}=2(101,111)\;\;,b_{4}=3(1111,1101,1011)$

Similarly $c_{1}=0\;\;,c_{2}=1(10)\;\;,c_{3} =1(110)\;\;,c_{4}=2(1110,1010)$

Now I did not understand How can I solve after that.

Help Required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition $a_n = b_n + c_n$.

If we have a correct number of length $n+1$ ending in $1$, then removing the final $1$ will always result in a correct number of length $n$ (of which there are $a_n$). And if we have a correct number of length $n$, we can always append a 1 to it, and get a correct number of lenght $n+1$, ending in $1$ (of which there are $b_{n+1}$), because the $1$ can never cause the 2 consecutive $0$ condition to fail.

So $b_{n+1} = a_n$ for all $n$. (This also holds for your small number examples, as you can see).

If we have a correct number of length $n+1$ ($n \ge 2$) ending in $0$, then it must end in $10$ as $00$ would have been illegal. Removing the final $10$ leaves us with a correct number of length $n-1$, of which there are $a_{n-1}$ by definition. Conversely again, having a correct number of length $n-1$ we can always add $10$ to it, which will never spoil the correctness, and get a valid number of length $n+1$ ending in $0$.

So $c_{n+1} = a_{n-1}$, as also can be seen from your examples.

So $a_{n+1} = b_{n+1} + c_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$ for all $n \ge 2$. I.e. we have a Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: What about part (1)? How would we do that?

Comment: The $b_n$ form a shifted Fibonacci sequence. So they're easy to compute once you have two consecutive values. @OsheenSachdev

Comment: Ah right...didn't quite understand the answer in the first go. Thank you!